# Go_Router, How to get result in previous page

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

In my project i am setting up go_router navigation and it works great for navigate, but i found two issues in two cases which i am mentioning below.

1. **Not found a proper way to pass result in previous page**

I have created a common function for routing in the whole app where i have defined all methods push, pop, remove. Now i need to setup a common method where i can pass some data into other screen and also need to get result in previos page when the second screen pop will going to be called.

```
static go(
  {required BuildContext context,
  required Mode mode,
  required String moveTo,
  var param}) async {
try {
  switch (mode) {
    case Mode.PUSH:
      context.push(RouteName.root + moveTo);
      break;
    case Mode.REPLACE:
      context.pushReplacement(RouteName.root + moveTo);
      break;
    case Mode.REMOVE:
      context.go(RouteName.root);
      context.pushReplacement(RouteName.root + moveTo);
      break;
    case Mode.POP:
      context.pop();
      break;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

}

2. **How to get page info during routing**

In go_router i am unable to find a way where i can get the current page information if i pop the screen B to screen A. I need to track user activity so in this case i need to fetch the route info when user go or back into any screen. Please guide me if there is any way with go_router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no way to do this. But someone have made a fork repo & implemented it which you can use.

Its on pub.dev with the name [go_router_flow](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router_flow). It's exactly like the original go_router with this pop with value feature.

Here is some example code:

```
final bool? result = await context.push<bool>('/page2');

WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  if(result){
    print('Page returned $result');
  }
});
```

You can read the discussion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99663)

Answer (score 2):

The package had an update by the nice people  Update to 6.5.5 and checkout [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html)

Waiting for a value:

```
onTap: () {
  final bool? result = await context.push<bool>('/page2');
  if(result ?? false)...
}`
```

Returning a value:

```
onTap: () => context.pop(true)
```